# Does ldstr internally implement newobj?

Tags: c#, .net, jit, cil, il

As we all know strings are implicitly instantiated, meaning that we don't have to use `new` in order to get a reference to an object of one.

Because of this it was always my belief that the framework is taking care of this, and hence I would get identical IL if I did something like this:

```
String first = new String(new char[] {'a'});
string second = "a";
```

However it appears that the first line is done using `newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.String::.ctor(char[])`
 and the second `ldstr "a"`.

So in order to obtain a string reference, does `ldstr` internally call `newobj` and where can I see the specification / details to back this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ldstr` gives you the reference to the literal string as [per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx) (remember literal strings are interned per default, so they are only created once). The first statement creates a regular instance of `string` using the `newobj` instruction as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`string` simply follows tha basic guideline for *reference* object types, that's why on `new`
you see `newobj`.

Infact if you try to write something like this, it will not generate `newobj`:

```
int a = new int();
a = 2;  
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

The resulting IL will be

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0003:  stloc.0     
IL_0004:  ldloc.0     
IL_0005:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

if you write just

```
int a = 2;  
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

result IL will be

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  ldloc.0     
IL_0003:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

No difference from allocation point of view (there is missed line naturally), cause we are talking about value type.

Comment: Yes. Who said that it shows? I show that unsing the same on value type doesn't inject that instruction.